# How to pass a function by reference in angular controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an angular app where I have two controllers in the order
Parent controller -> Child controller, where the child controller gets called only when the parent controller has completely executed.

I am using an object on the scope to pass properties from the Parent to the Child controller which is working fine.

However, now I want to pass a function in the same order, but I am not able to access it from the Child controller.

parentController.js

```
function ParentController($scope) {
  ...
  function _loadCarrierObject() {
    $scope.carrierObject = {};
    $scope.carrierObject.foo = bar;
    ...
    $scope.carrierObject.getUpdates = _fetchUpdates;
}

function _fetchUpdates() {
  ...
}
```

childController.js

```
function getUpdates() {
  $scope.carrierObject.foo;            // returns bar
  $scope.carrierObject.getUpdates();   // returns undefined
}
```

EDIT: I should have been explicit. I was trying with using the function keyword with both the function definitions.

Comment: is this a typo? `_fetchUpdates() {` your missing a the `function` keyword

Comment: did you try to use `$scope.$parent`

Comment: @LouieAlmeda it's a typo

Answer (score 2):

You could just $rootScope.$emit and event that your parent controller listens for and this does the work of your function?

Example:

```
app.controller('ParentCtrl', function ParentCtrl ($scope) {
 $scope.$on('child', function (event, data) {
   console.log('foo');
 });
});

app.controller('ChildCtrl', function ChildCtrl ($scope) {
 $scope.$emit('child', 'bar');
});
```

Comment: This is an option. But I want to use the 'carrierObject' that I have already implemented in my system.

Comment: I think you would call your carrierObject function in the $scope.$on in the parentController.

Answer (score 0):

you are just missing the `function` keyword

```
function _fetchUpdates() {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is fetchUpdates() actually returning undefined or is it giving you an 'undefined is not a function' error?

If the former, this may be an issue with _fetchUpdates() and not how you're passing it. Maybe it is an async issue? Can you share that function's body?

@Emjay has the more correct answer though. It's considered a bad practice to establish such tight dependency between controllers. Better to use message passing on $rootScope.

Answer (score 0):

<s>A function can be called within another function by just invoking its name but it can't be assigned to a reference within another function.</s> Create a reference to the function and then pass it to the child controller. Something like below should work

```
function ParentController($scope) {
  ...
  $scope.fetchUpdates = _fetchUpdates;

  function _loadCarrierObject() {
    $scope.carrierObject = {};
    $scope.carrierObject.foo = bar;
    ...
    $scope.carrierObject.getUpdates = $scope.fetchUpdates;
  }

  function _fetchUpdates() {
  ...
  }

}
```

BTW, the code looks incomplete so I just added the closing braces where necessary.

See this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/3H0xn6cDa2lPEgqeKIFS?p=preview) for more info. Hit F12 on Chrome to see the output of the plunkr in the console.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not right, you don't have to assign the function to a reference first. I even tried it in your plunkr to be sure and the function reference works both ways.

Comment: @Jason Winneback. You're right, it does! Removed the incorrect statement. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you showed us, it should work to put the function reference in an object that is on the scope.

I would not agree that is good style though. However, there is not really a thing as "parent" and "child" controllers. If you want to communicate between two controllers, the ideal way is to create a shared service. If you really have a parent/child relationship for example a "display user" directive that inside of it has an "update user button" directive, you should use directives that explicitly declare the relationship with require.

If the components aren't really related except that they share data, then you can just use two directives where you pass in the same object to both in your template.